# How to generate key value when using EmbeddedId

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

I am fairly new to Java & JPA. The issue I am facing is I have a Entity using EmbeddedId. The javadoc says that `@GeneratedValue` cannot be used for other than simple primary keys.

After some searching the approach I implemented is, create a entity "sequence_table" & manually read the value, increment it by once, updating the current value, using that value to create the EmbeddedId & all this is done in synchronized method.

Is this approach fine or is there any better approach to generate id when using EmbeddedId ? I am also thinking about pre-allocating & caching ids, same as done by GeneratedValue.

Is there any existing solution for this or am I reinventing ?

**Update:**
Code for entity is as below

```
@Entity
public class TransactionDetails {
   @EmbededId
   TransactionKey id;
}

@Embedded
public class TransactionKey {
    Integer id;
    String  storeId;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why you would want to do that. An EmbeddedId should be a multipart id made up of multiple fields from other records or information outside of the Class/Table that's using the EmbeddedId. If you are using a generated value for the table then just use Id.

Comment: @Nicholas The schema is existing & the entity's primary key is a composite key (generate value , store id). I think the composite key can be compromised of keys from existing entities or may be combination of existing keys from other entities & generated value ?

Comment: It looks like the composite key you show is using the storeId as a foreign key, meaning you probably have a list of things that belong to a store. You should consider putting a list of your entities in your store entity and annotating it with OneToMany, that might match the existing schema. Also, to get meaningful help here it's best to make a small sample code. Without that I have to make many assumptions about what your really asking about which may be wrong.